# Populating empty elements of a column in a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Please refer to this sample data:

```
# |IDNum |Date     |data |SomeDate |TranCode
1|888888| 12/16/10|aaaaa|         |a10
2|888888| 12/16/10|bbbbb| 11/16/15|a8
3|888888| 12/16/10|ccccc|         |a11
4|888888| 11/16/10|aaaaa|         |a6
5|888888| 11/16/10|bbbbb|         |a5
6|888888| 11/16/10|ccccc| 10/16/15|a9
7|888888| 11/16/10|aaaaa|         |a11
8|888888| 11/15/10|bbbbb|         |a3
9|888888| 10/16/10|ccccc|         |a6
10|888888| 10/16/10|aaaaa|         |a5
11|888888| 10/16/10|bbbbb| 09/16/15|a9
12|888888| 10/16/10|ccccc|         |a11
13|888888| 09/16/10|aaaaa|         |a6
14|888888| 09/16/10|bbbbb| 08/16/15|a5
15|888888| 09/16/10|ccccc|         |a9
16|111111| 03/02/15|aaaaa|         |a9
17|111111| 02/27/15|bbbbb| 12/01/15|a6
18|111111| 02/10/15|ccccc|         |a1
19|111111| 02/01/15|aaaaa|         |a10
20|111111| 02/01/15|bbbbb| 11/01/15|a9
21|111111| 01/05/15|ccccc|         |a10
22|111111| 01/05/15|aaaaa| 10/01/15|a9
23|111111| 12/31/14|bbbbb|         |a12
24|111111| 12/30/14|ccccc|         |a2
25|111111| 12/01/14|aaaaa|         |a6
26|111111| 12/01/14|bbbbb| 10/01/15|a10
```

I have the above data stored as a list delimited by pipes and sorted by Date descending. I would need the "SomeDate" field to populate using the last date available in the row for that particular IDNumber.

So for example:

- Row 1 should show a date of 11/16/15.
- Row 3:5 should show a date of 10/16/15.
- Row 7:10 should show a date of 09/16/15
- Row 15 should show no date since there is no preceding date for that IDNum.
- Row 16 should show a date of 12/01/15

Any logic recommendations would be much appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify - The data posted above is currently stored in a list. What I need help with is coming up with logic of how to solve my problem.

Comment: You'll need to post what you have so far. SO is about fixing broken code, not general algorithm help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full writeup of how to solve this issue.  Note that I put the sample data into C:\test\sample.txt for ease of use.

```
public class FileData
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string IDNum { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string SomeDate { get; set; }
    public string TranCode { get; set; }
}

public class ReadFile
{
    public string SampleFile = @"C:\test\sample.txt";


    public ReadFile()
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(SampleFile);
        string sampleFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        string[] lines = sampleFile.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string previousDate = "";
        List<FileData> fileDatas = new List<FileData>();

        for (int i = lines.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            FileData data = new FileData();
            string[] columns = lines[i].Split('|');
            data.ID = columns[0].Trim();
            data.IDNum = columns[1].Trim();
            data.Date = columns[2].Trim();
            data.Data = columns[3].Trim();
            string someDate = columns[4].Trim();
            if (someDate.Equals(""))
            {
                data.SomeDate = previousDate;
            }
            else
            {
                previousDate = someDate;
                data.SomeDate = someDate;
            }
            data.TranCode = columns[5].Trim();
            fileDatas.Add(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Please notice that I created a "FileData" class to use to store the values.

Also notice that I am going through this data backwards, as it's easier to assign the dates this way.

What this does:

This reads all the data from the file into a string.  That string is then split by line ends (\r\n).

Once you have a list of lines, we go BACKWARDS through it (int i = lines.length - 1; i < 0; i--).

Going backwards, we simply assign data, except for the "somedate" column.  Here we check to see if somedate has a value. If it does, we assign a "previousDate" variable that value, and then assign the value.  If it doesn't have a value, we use the value from previousDate.  This ensures it will change appropriately.

The one issue with this is actually a potential issue with the data.  If the end of the file does not have a date, you will have blank values for the SomeDate column until the first time you encounter a date.

Compiled, tested, and working.

Comment: I sincerely hope this wasn't a homework assignment :-)

Comment: LOL - No, even better...I'm getting paid for your work. Very much appreciated :)

Comment: Buy me a beer if you're ever in Grand Rapids ;-)

Comment: I have 2 questions: In the example above I wouldn't want row 15 to take on row 17's "SomeDate" because they have different IDNum's. How would you validate this? I was thinking of mimicking what you did with previousDate and having a placeholder IDNum as a validation. My second question is how would I output the fileDatas list to a text file? When I do a WriteAllLines I get a whole array of errors such as system.ArgumentException, IO.DirectoryNotFoundException, IO.PathTooLongException, Security.SecurityException...etc. I have WriteAllLines in my code and it doesnt error out like in this case.

Comment: It sounds like your validation would work.   The second question is a little more in depth, and I'm not quite sure how you're outputting your data.  If you update your question or ask another I can look at it

Comment: Right: I'd like to output to a text file like so:

File.WriteAllLines(ParentDirectory + "\\EXTRACTED_FORMATTED - " + Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text) + ".txt",  fileDatas,Encoding.UTF8);

However Im getting the errors I posted before. Any suggestions? I know its something really basic -___-